# Why onclick event suppressed, when preventDefault() is called for the touchstart event?

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad

I try to implement some javascript functions for my Ipad device. I would like to use some swipe action and click action on my canvas div.

I implemented the horizontal and the vertical swipe function. I have to use the preventDefault on the touchstart event to prevent the full page scrolling, when swiping. It worked well, but after this I noticed that it disabled every click event on this div. When the preventDefault is removed the click event works again.

Is there any solution to solve this problem?

```
dojo.connect(this.node, "ontouchstart", this, "touchstart"); 

...   

touchstart: function(e){
    this.touch = dojo.clone(e.changedTouches[0]);
    e.preventDefault();   
}
```

this.node = document.getElementById('aa');

```
<div id="aa" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;">
  <div onclick="alert('asd');" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #ff0000; margin: auto;">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post your Javascript and HTML code please?

Comment: I just added the relevant part of the code.

Comment: hmm, could you also post what `this.node` is?

Comment: Added some html code, the full code is very complicated and this can produce the same bad result. Currently I'm thinking about emulating the mouse click, when the distance beetween the touchstart and touchend is very short. http://cubiq.org/remove-onclick-delay-on-webkit-for-iphone

Comment: Just tested, this click emulation work like a charm.

Comment: You could try to prevent the default action of the `touchmove` event.

Comment: @Prusse: Nice, it works fine and more simplier. Please make an answer and I will accept. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to prevent the default action of the touchmove event.

Answer (score 9):

I know Prusse has already answered this question correctly, but it lacks the confidence I search for in an answer. The reason the click event suppressed by preventDefault() in touchstart is because any event connected and following touchstart will be suppressed. **The solution is to add preventDefault() to the touchmove event instead.**

This is explained in more detail in the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Touch_events) under **Handling Clicks**:

> Since calling preventDefault() on a touchstart or the first touchmove
>   event of a series prevents the corresponding mouse events from firing,
>   it's common to call preventDefault() on touchmove rather than
>   touchstart. That way, mouse events can still fire and things like
>   links will continue to work.