# event.preventDefault() stopping all javascript in chrome on android

Tags: android, google-chrome, onclick, touch-event, preventdefault

i have the following event listeners defined in vanilla js

```
link.addEventListener("touchstart", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
});

link.addEventListener("touchend", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});

link.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

The event being prevented is a page load (the target elements are a tags)

Elsewhere (in a different JS file) there is code which makes a dropdown appear when the targeted elements are clicked on.

This works fine in many other browsers (chrome pc and mac, firefox pc, safari mac, edge, IE 11, iphone safari, ipad safari)

but chrome on android is behaving differently

with those preventDefault statements on the dropdown menu does not appear when the links are clicked.

I have tested this by commenting out the preventDefaults and the dropdowns appear.

chrome dev tools shows that the first preventDefault is the one being run when they are not commented out.

what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

It's because touchstart prevents click event. You can prevent touchmove instead to prevent links. See related question - [Why onclick event suppressed, when preventDefault() is called for the touchstart event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780965/why-onclick-event-suppressed-when-preventdefault-is-called-for-the-touchstart)

Comment: Lots of thx man