# Javascript prevent click fire when drag happens

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag

I am using this code for dragging container left / right. This works well. User can also click on the "thumb". The problem is that click happens also after drag. It should be either drag or click. How can I isolate one or another? It has to work on tablets of course.

```js
var thumbContainer = document.querySelector('.aplbox-thumb-container'),
  thumbContainerWrap = document.querySelector('.aplbox-thumb-container-wrap'),
  startXThumb,
  startTouchThumb

if ("ontouchstart" in window) {
  thumbContainer.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStartThumb);
}
thumbContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStartThumb);


function dragStartThumb(e) {

  if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation()


  if (!startTouchThumb) {
    startTouchThumb = true;

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', dragMoveThumb)
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', dragEndThumb);

    if ("ontouchstart" in window) {
      document.addEventListener('touchmove', dragMoveThumb)
      document.addEventListener('touchend', dragEndThumb);
    }

    var point;
    if (e.type == 'touchstart') {
      var touches = e.changedTouches;

      if (touches.length > 1) {
        return false;
      }
      point = touches[0];
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      point = e;
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    var currX = thumbContainer.style.transform.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
    currX = parseInt(currX) || 0;

    startXThumb = point.pageX + currX;

  }

}

function dragMoveThumb(e) {
  if (startTouchThumb) {

    var point;
    if (e.type == 'touchmove') {
      var touches = e.changedTouches;

      if (touches.length > 1) {
        return false;
      }
      point = touches[0];
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      point = e;
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    var diff = point.pageX - startXThumb;

    if (diff > 0) diff = 0;
    else if (diff < -thumbContainer.offsetWidth + thumbContainerWrap.offsetWidth) diff = -thumbContainer.offsetWidth + thumbContainerWrap.offsetWidth;

    thumbContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(' + diff + 'px)';

  }

}

function dragEndThumb(e) {

  e.stopPropagation()

  if (startTouchThumb) {
    startTouchThumb = false;

    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', dragMoveThumb)
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', dragEndThumb);

    if ("ontouchstart" in window) {
      document.removeEventListener('touchmove', dragMoveThumb)
      document.removeEventListener('touchend', dragEndThumb);
    }

  }
}

//click thumb
thumbContainerWrap.addEventListener('click', function(e) {


  if (e.target.closest('.aplbox-thumb')) {



    console.log('click')

  }

})
```

```css
.aplbox-thumb-container-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.aplbox-thumb-container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  transform: translateX(0);
  touch-action: none;
}

.aplbox-thumb {
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #333;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="aplbox-thumb-container-wrap">
  <div class="aplbox-thumb-container" style="width: 1300px;">
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="0"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="1"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="2"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="3"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="4"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="5"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="6"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="7"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="8"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="9"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="10"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="11"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you try using flag? you can set flag false on touchstart then set it true on touchend.
and for click set condition ```if ( ! flag) return```

Comment: Hope this helps. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19431746/20946150
Good luck!

Comment: @Amirhoseinh73 Yes, the same demo Lukas wrote below , but click is not registered on mobile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the variable `moved`. In the `dragStartThumb` function set this variable to false, and in the `dragMoveThumb` function set it to true and in the `onclick` event check this variable. Like below. 
 Something like @Amirhoseinh73 wrote, but instead of setting the flag to true in the `touchend` function we set the flag to true in the `mousemove` function, because we don't want have always variable set to true.

```js
var thumbContainer = document.querySelector('.aplbox-thumb-container'),
  thumbContainerWrap = document.querySelector('.aplbox-thumb-container-wrap'),
  startXThumb,
  startTouchThumb
  
let moved = false;

if ("ontouchstart" in window) {
      thumbContainer.addEventListener("touchstart", dragStartThumb);
}
    
thumbContainer.addEventListener("mousedown", dragStartThumb);


function dragStartThumb(e) {
   moved = false;
   
  //if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation()

  if (!startTouchThumb) {
    startTouchThumb = true;

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', dragMoveThumb)
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', dragEndThumb);

    if ("ontouchstart" in window) {
      document.addEventListener('touchmove', dragMoveThumb)
      document.addEventListener('touchend', dragEndThumb);
    }

    var point;
    if (e.type == 'touchstart') {
      var touches = e.changedTouches;

      if (touches.length > 1) {
        return false;
      }
      point = touches[0];
      //e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      point = e;
      //e.preventDefault();
    }

    var currX = thumbContainer.style.transform.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '');
    currX = parseInt(currX) || 0;

    startXThumb = point.pageX + currX;

  }

}

function dragMoveThumb(e) {
  moved = true;
    
  if (startTouchThumb) {

    var point;
    if (e.type == 'touchmove') {
      var touches = e.changedTouches;

      if (touches.length > 1) {
        return false;
      }
      point = touches[0];
      e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      point = e;
      e.preventDefault();
    }

    var diff = point.pageX - startXThumb;

    if (diff > 0) diff = 0;
    else if (diff < -thumbContainer.offsetWidth + thumbContainerWrap.offsetWidth) diff = -thumbContainer.offsetWidth + thumbContainerWrap.offsetWidth;

    thumbContainer.style.transform = 'translateX(' + diff + 'px)';

  }

}

function dragEndThumb(e) {
e.stopPropagation()
  if (startTouchThumb) {
    startTouchThumb = false;

    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', dragMoveThumb)
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', dragEndThumb);

    if ("ontouchstart" in window) {
      document.removeEventListener('touchmove', dragMoveThumb)
      document.removeEventListener('touchend', dragEndThumb);
    }

  }
}

//click thumb
thumbContainerWrap.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.closest('.aplbox-thumb') && !moved) {

    console.log('click')

  }

})
```

```css
.aplbox-thumb-container-wrap {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.aplbox-thumb-container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 5px 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  transform: translateX(0);
  touch-action: none;
}

.aplbox-thumb {
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: #333;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="aplbox-thumb-container-wrap">
  <div class="aplbox-thumb-container" style="width: 1300px;">
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="0"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="1"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="2"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="3"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="4"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="5"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="6"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="7"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="8"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="9"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="10"></div>
    <div class="aplbox-thumb" data-id="11"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But click doesnt work when I test on mobile . The same when I use device toolbar on chrome and test this demo.

Comment: @Toniq you can't use e.preventDefault() in touchstart event, because it suppresses the onclick event.  I have updated my answer. More here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6780965/why-onclick-event-suppressed-when-preventdefault-is-called-for-the-touchstart.

Comment: It does work now, and with stopPropagation on start and end events, plus preventDefault in move event. Thats a lot to know.